Does Jn 12:27 teach that one should consult God before making a prayer?
We see Jesus praying in Jn 12:27 ( NRSVCE):

“Now my soul is troubled. And what should I say—‘Father, save me from this hour’? No, it is for this reason that I have come to this hour.

Many people lose  faith after finding their prayer unanswered. Here,  we see Jesus consulting the Father whether he should pray for being saved from the ordeal of Passion . Jesus  refrains from making that prayer and in stead prays that the Name of the Father be glorified (Verse 28)
My question is : Does Jn 12:27 teach that one should consult God before making a prayer ?

Could "And what should I say — ‘Father, save me from this hour’?" not simply be a rhetorical question?

Good observation. But Jesus continues in the same breath: "No, it is what I am here for ". That implies that he is weighing the options.

Short Answer: No.
This is a description not a prescription.
The model is to prioritize seeking God’s will over our personal desires. Jesus makes a decision to not ask for deliverance from His impending suffering, but rather instead to pray for the Father’s name to be glorified (John 12:28).
Notice the Lord's prayer:
Matthew 6:9-10 ESV

9 Pray then like this:
“Our Father in heaven, hallowed be your name. 10 Your kingdom come,
your will be done,
on earth as it is in heaven.

The model is that we pray for God's will to be done. Not ours. Do people lose faith after not having their prayer answered? Yes. But sometimes the most profound blessings from God come in the form of unanswered prayers.

The question involves an implied self-contradiction.  Why?  Because asking God for permission to pray is a prayer to God!!
Therefore, the answer to OP's question is "NO!".
We often see many prayers, particularly those recorded in the Psalms by David and other that question God; question God's willingness to do something, etc.  All this is OK with God.  Indeed, as many have noted, the psalms almost demand that we are honest enough with God to express our doubts!
A perfect example of this is the prayer first uttered by David and repeated by (in part) Jesus:

Ps 22:1 - My God, my God, why have You forsaken me? Why are You so far
from saving me, so far from my words of groaning? I cry out by day, O
my God, but You do not answer, and by night, but I have no rest.

Now, the very fact that God is omnipresent means, as Paul expressed it -

Acts 17:27 - God did this so that they would seek him and perhaps
reach out for him and find him, though he is not far from any one of
us.

Thus, in Jesus' prayer in John 12:27, Jesus reveals His humanity because He knows the almost superhuman ordeal ahead of Him.  Indeed, even in the Garden before the day of his crucifixion, three times Jesus prayed:

Matt 26:39 -  “My Father, if it is possible, let this cup pass from
Me. Yet not as I will, but as You will.”  See also V42, 44.

We do not need permission to pray because God encourages us to "pray continually" (1 Thess 5:17), and to be "faithful in prayer" (Rom 12:12).  Indeed, it was the Lord Himself who told a parable whose spiritual lesson was to "always pray and not give up." Luke 18:1.
